# 3 abstract classes-1superclass,2subclass....how do i call the method from the both subclasses

Tags: java, abstract

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

abstract class n { 
    int i=5;  
    abstract void showme();  
    abstract void display1();    
    void display() {  
        System.out.println(i);
    } 
}

abstract class p extends n {
    int i=2;   
    void showme(){
        System.out.println("7");
    }
}


abstract class q extends n {
    void display1() {
        System.out.println("10");
    }
}

public class m { 
    public static void main(String a[]) {
    }
}
```

How do i call the 2 methods since all the classes are abstract...i dont want to use showme in class 'q' and display1 in class 'p'

Comment: Arghhh, dont let your pets run over your keyboard... if it was not an earthquake :-(

Comment: What methods do you actually want to call? There are quite a few and "the 2" isn't a good indicator.

Answer (score -1):

The Problem seems to be that your superclass 'n' is itself abstract and both the subclasses p ,q are abstract  too and *abstract classes cant be instantiated* i.e. objects of that can't be created so **there is no way by which you can call the two methods display1() and showme()**,

One possible hint would be for example to make 'm' a superclass of 'n' , so in that case you can use

ie

```
 abstract class n extends m

 m m1=new n(); //which is fine due to polymorphism and invoke the methods on m1
```

Hope that Helps !

Comment: Ignoring the fact that formatting problems should be reported in comments, and that *your* code is badly formatted as well (no indentation), **it does not compile**. Not only are the statements outside of a method or initialization block, you are also trying to create instances of abstract classes (without anonymous classes or any sort of concrete subclassing).

Comment: @Ordous Sorry didnt notice , Edited

Comment: Eh, I still disagree. With `class m extends n` it's illegal to write `m obj = new n();` both because `n` is abstract and because m is not assignable from n. `n obj = new m();` would be legal however.

Comment: @Ordous Please Note that i said make 'm' a SuperClass of 'n' , which implies `class n extends m`

Comment: You still can't instantiate `n` and you don't have access to *any* methods other than the ones specified in `m` then.

Comment: @Ordous       Oops my bad , sorry